# Перенес div элементов на новую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть `div` у которого стоят такие свойства:

```
   #main_div{

        position: absolute;
        padding: 5px 14px 15px 0px;
        top: 50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        max-width: 350px;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
```

в него по клику добавляются элементы с такими свойствами:

```
  #div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: 16px;
        width: 67px;
        margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

почему происходит сразу перенос на новую строку `#div`, а не когда ширина `#main_div` достигнет 350px и только потом перенос на новую строку.

Answer (score 2):

1. Забыли задать `#main_div` `display: flex;`
2. Если будет несколько блоков внутри, то стоит задавать класс, а не `id`

```js
$('#main_div').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      box = '<div class="div">Lorem ipsum.</div>';
  
  $this.append(box);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main_div{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 14px 15px 0px;
  top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 16px;
  width: 67px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<span>Кликните на блок ниже &darr;</span>
<div id="main_div">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Но блок уже шириной 350px,  а  мне нужно чтобы это было постепенно, то есть сначала там один элемент, и он шириной допустим 100 px, потом 2 элемента и шириной 200 px. потом 3 элемента и шириной 300px, но потом уже элементы переносились на другую строку

Comment: все переносится, поправила ответ, что теперь по клику добавляются. 4-ый уже не влазит и начинает переноситься

Comment: Так он изначально шириной большой, мне нужно чтобы был перенос, только когда достигнет max-width

Comment: @ЭльдарГучеренко, мне кажется Вы сами не понимаете чего хотите!!

Answer (score 1):

Это больше длинный комментарий, чем ответ.  Совет, - чтобы можно было дать более внятный и конструктивный ответ, судя по комментариям под ответом `HamSter`, советую добавить весь код. Но из того примера, что есть, можно сказать так. Ты добавляешь несколько  элементов  `#div`.
`ID` это уникальный идентификатор.

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

И не может быть несколько элементов  с таким ID

```
<div id="div"></div>
<div id="div"></div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Вот такая конструкция неправильная

У элемента может быть несколько классов. Например

```
<div class="div wrapper main-wrapper"> </div>
```

Один класс может быть у нескольких элементов Например

```
  <div class="div wrapper main-wrapper"></div>
  <p class="wrapper"></p>
```

Но ID может и должен быть единственный и только у одно элемента...

И еще. Судя по этому блоку правил

```
   #div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: 16px;
        width: 67px;
        margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

вот эти правила

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

для родительского элемента. В этом блоке есть что-то?